# Native Modules: difference between { Component } = NativeModules and requireNativeComponent('Component')

Tags: react-native

I'm a little confused. I just did these two tutorials to start writing my own native modules in Swift:

https://teabreak.e-spres-oh.com/swift-in-react-native-the-ultimate-guide-part-1-modules-9bb8d054db03

https://teabreak.e-spres-oh.com/swift-in-react-native-the-ultimate-guide-part-2-ui-components-907767123d9e

The first one is a viewless module and is imported like this:

```
const { Module } = NativeModules;
```

The second is a native component with a view and is imported like this:

```
const ImageBlendView = requireNativeComponent('ImageBlendView')
```

Are these in some way interchangeable or does the existence or non-existence of a UI View make a fundamental difference?